# Search to show SPS List item with default view link only

Tags: search, list-view, item, default

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Is it possible while searching for a SharePoint List item, the link provided in search shows only the default view page link and not other views link.

Example: I have a SharePoint 2013 list that has 3 views -

a) default
b) administrator
c) multipleedit

While searching for an item in the global search, it shows the item information, but provides links for all views.

We dont want basic users to be able to view the administrator view and expect the search to show only the default view.

Kindly suggest if its possible?

Comment: As far as I know, the search results should only show the elements which the user has permission to. So if the url of the administrators view is not permitted to the user, he/she should not get that result. Am I wrong?

Comment: @patrick, well testing so far confirms for users with basic access rights are able to view links for administrator in their search.

Answer (score 0):

Trimmed security applies to the contents of the View, not the View itself.

Do not create a View in the List, instead Create a Page (for admins only) with a ListView on it.

You might want to create a separate Pages library so its easier to govern permissions, and exclude the content from being indexed by Search

Comment: that is not possible in my case. As the admin wants to view all list items and in the default view only items with the closing date till the end of the month are allowed. So you need 2 viewws for a sps list. Wondering how listview on another pg will help. As list view will show data from default view n if i want all data thwn need to have another view first.

Comment: You can put multiple ListView WebParts on one (administrator) page, they can be the same views as you now have on the list, they are just not declared ON the list, so only available on the admins page. If you put the page in a library only admins can access and exclude it from being indexed it won't show up in Search